# Express static запросы тригерят роутер

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, ssr

Всем привет, я пишу ssr react приложение и заметил такую проблему:

Мне нужно отлавливать все урлы, потомучто у меня есть хендлер со статическим роутером, который сам отрендерить что ему надо, в зависимости от урла.
У меня так же есть статик мидлвар. Проблема заключается в том, что express все равно тригериться на статик запросы и отдает вместо скрипта разметку. Я предполагаю это потому, что я отлавливаю все '*' запросы, но я не хочу отлавливать статику :(

Я не силен в express, как можно решить данную проблему?

```
const server = express();

server.set('view engine', 'ejs');
server.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));

const manifest = fs.readFileSync(
    path.join(__dirname, 'static/manifest.json'),
    'utf-8',
);
const assets = JSON.parse(manifest);

server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    handleRequest(req.url, routes).then(({component, __REACT_QUERY_STATE__ = ''}) => {
        res.render('client', { assets, component, __REACT_QUERY_STATE__ });
    });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server running on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

Comment: Не подскажу вам конкретно по вашему вопросу, отвечу на подвопрос) по сравнению с экспрессом - fastify шустрее раза в 2-3

Answer (score 0):

Замените middleware которое обрабатывает все ваши get запросы на следуйщее -

```
server.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.path.startsWith('/static') {
      return next();
    }

    handleRequest(req.url, routes).then(({component, __REACT_QUERY_STATE__ = ''}) => {
        res.render('client', { assets, component, __REACT_QUERY_STATE__ });
    });
});
```

просто проверяем урл, если начинается с урла где хранятся ваши статические файлы - вызываем next()